# How to use wow.js for a web page that show content from bottom to top

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to use wow js animations for a web page with inverse scrolling. When the page loads the scroll bar is at top. But shows the content which are at bottom of the page. In natural scroll,bottom content will slide down and the top content will be displayed accordingly.
I used wow js animations but they are not visible and not animating till you scroll to the bottom of the page.(in my case the scroll bar will be at the bottom and bottom most content will be displayed)
I tried editing the wow.js file but I'm not good at js. I would be really grateful if anyone could help me find a solution. Thank you.

Comment: Please see this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/5UUtV/1/) to see the sample structure of my web page